# What will be a good choice for a layout of network graph in gephi

Tags: layout, graph, gephi

I would like to layout a network graph in gephi, which in many cases looks like the one below. What will be a good choice for my layout?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Force Atlas 2 or Fruchterman Reingold would give you results similar as the one here. Both are installed by default in Gephi.